# Why did they add comedy in "John Wick 3"?

Tags: john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

I think *John Wick Chapter 3: Parabellum* shifts a bit away from the previous two movies in some aspects, but what intrigued me the most was the factor of comic-style humor added into it.

The part where the Japanese ninja keeps talking and joking with a katana inside him feels awkward and out-of-context.

**Why were these comedic scenes added to *John Wick 3*?**

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea why this is being downvoted. Sure, it's opinionated, but it definitely comes across as a genuine question about the shift in tone, and not just a "why did they do this thing I don't like?!" kind of rant.

Comment: It might not be comedy intentionally per say. People dying may say some weird things. If I had to guess, I'd say you were downvoted because it seems like your question is fairly opinion based.

Comment: Reading the quotes in Raj's answer I think it's fair to assume the question is not opinion based anymore...

Answer (score 2):

About his character Zero, Dacascos told [Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/article/55812-john-wick-chapter-3-mark-dacascos-on-race-samurai-training-and-power-rangers):

> He feels like John’s brother from a different mother. That’s him! It’s
>   not meant to be funny. It’s very sincere.

About working with Reeves and Stahelski, he told [Vulture](https://www.vulture.com/2019/05/john-wick-3s-mark-dacascos-on-working-with-keanu-reeves.html):

> Chad yells, “Cut!” Then Keanu starts laughing and drops some F-bombs,
>   and says, “That’s too funny. We can’t do that, right?” There’s a beat,
>   and I hear Chad from the back go, “I love it. We’re doing it.” And
>   that’s how that take evolved.

So at least some of the interaction between the two characters appears to have been ad-libbed.
Vulture's editor also added:

> After reaching out to representatives at Lionsgate, Vulture learned
>   that Hiroyuki Sanada, who starred in 47 Ronin alongside Reeves, was
>   originally cast in the role of Zero.

So it's possible that the humor may not have been added, if Sanada had not been replaced.